# What is the best way to store JSON in Postgres

Tags: json, postgresql

What is the best way to store JSON data in Postgres? Is it possible to query a stored json string without using like/regex?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The best option is to use a column defined as `jsonb`.

And yes, Postgres has [a lot of functions](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/current/functions-json.html) that let you query the content of a JSON value.

e.g. to check if a key/value pair is contained in the value `json_column @> '{"key": "value"}'`

Comment: Using non ANSI column types can bring problems when using ORMs. Is jsonb well supported by ORMs like hibernate, Doctrine, etc?

Comment: If you want to criple yourself to the abilities of an obfuscation layer then don't use JSON in the first place. You asked for the best way to do it in Postgres. Not the best way to do it with an ORM. The SQL standard defines JSON access function, but unfortunately, Postgres doesn't implement the functions in the way the standard defines them. Plus: I doubt any ORM actually supports ANSI SQL on that level. jOOQ supports all Postgres JSON feature if I'm not mistaken